Multiple LLM steps with passed output and streaming response in the last one
I'm trying to create a chain of multiple steps where the input for step one is a system message + user message, and its output is passed to a second step with a new system message. However, the fourth step should be a streaming response.
system_message 1 + user message 1 -> output 1  
system_message 2 + output 1 -> output 2  
system_message 3 + output 2 -> output 3  
system_message 4 + output 3 -> output 4 [STREAMING RESPONSE]

How do I do that with LCEL?
Tried to search in the documentation, but I can't get a working example.

maybe you can use transfomers like:
from transformers import TextStreamer

streamer = TextStreamer(tokenizer, skip_prompt=True, skip_special_tokens=True)

generated_ids = model.generate(model_inputs.input_ids,max_new_tokens=512,streamer=streamer)

